# I created a procedure and type after thast,i just modified a column in procedure cursor and type

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I create a procedure and type after compilation I just modified a column in procedure cursor and type but in when I try to compile procedure it returns an error:

> Error(94,65): PLS-00302: component 'REQUESTED' must be declared

Code:

```
--type creation code.
CREATE or REPLACE TYPE return_security_report AS OBJECT (                  
    requestId                   NUMBER  ,
        room                        VARCHAR2(256),
    firstName                   VARCHAR2(60),
    lastName      VARCHAR2(60),
CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION return_security_report RETURN SELF AS RESULT
);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY return_security_report AS
      CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION return_security_report RETURN SELF AS RESULT AS
      BEGIN
               SELF.requestId          := NULL;
               SELF.room           := NULL;
               SELF.firstName       := NULL;
               SELF.lastName    := NULL;             
         RETURN;
      END;
END;
/
CREATE TYPE return_security_arr_result AS VARRAY(10000) OF return_security_report;
/


---procedure code
create or replace PROCEDURE BIQ_SECURITY_REPORT 
             (out_chr_err_code   OUT VARCHAR2,
              out_chr_err_msg    OUT VARCHAR2,
              out_security_tab   OUT return_security_arr_result   ,

             )
IS             

      l_chr_srcstage     VARCHAR2 (200);
      l_chr_biqtab       VARCHAR2 (200);
      l_chr_srctab       VARCHAR2 (200);
      l_chr_bistagtab    VARCHAR2 (200);
      l_chr_err_code     VARCHAR2 (255);
      l_chr_err_msg      VARCHAR2 (255);
      l_out_chr_errbuf   VARCHAR2 (2000);
      lrec               return_security_report;


CURSOR cur_security_data IS
    SELECT
    "ID"                  "requestId",
    "ROOM"                "room",
    "FIRST_NAME"          "FIRST_NAME",
    "LAST_NAME"           "LAST_NAME",

FROM
   "BI_REQUEST_CATERING_ACTIVITY" ;

   TYPE rec_security_data IS TABLE OF cur_security_data%ROWTYPE
   INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
   l_cur_security_data   rec_security_data;  


begin


      OPEN cur_security_data;

      LOOP      
         FETCH cur_security_data
         BULK COLLECT INTO l_cur_security_data
         LIMIT 1000;

         EXIT WHEN l_cur_security_data.COUNT = 0;

        lrec := return_security_report();
        out_security_tab  := return_security_arr_result(return_security_report());
        out_security_tab.delete;


                 FOR i IN 1 .. l_cur_security_data.COUNT
                 LOOP


--                       dbms_output.put_line('Inside cursor   '  );

                               BEGIN  

                                    l_num_counter                := l_num_counter + 1;
                                    lrec                         := return_security_report();
                                    lrec.requestid              := l_cur_security_data(i).requestId ;                                   lrec.room                 := l_cur_security_data(i).room ;                                  lrec.firstName              := l_cur_security_data(i).firstName ;
--                                  lrec.lastName               := l_cur_security_data(i).lastName ;


                                    IF l_num_counter > 1 
                                    THEN
                                       out_security_tab.extend();
                                       out_security_tab(l_num_counter) := return_security_report();
                                    ELSE
                                       out_security_tab := return_security_arr_result(return_security_report());
                                    END IF;
                                       out_security_tab(l_num_counter) := lrec; 

                               EXCEPTION             
                                  WHEN OTHERS 
                                  THEN
                                    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error occurred : '  || SQLERRM);
                              END; 

                        END LOOP;              
       END LOOP;              


   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('HERE INSIIDE OTHERS' || SQLERRM);
   END;
```

when I try to update the filed names in type then onwards procedure compiler through error even though after modification of procedures.
Pls, post a solution for this.

> "Error":- like "Error(94,65): PLS-00302: component 'REQUESTID' must be declared"

Comment: Try looking for optimizing the code as I can see unnecessary looping done. You can directly fetch into the `OUT` parameter from your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the behavior of ORACLE.

You have defined "requestId" in your cursor as case sensitive and you need to use it in case sensitive manner only.

so following changes in your code is needed: (same for other variables)

```
lrec.requestId := l_cur_security_data(i)."requestId" ; -- use it with " (double qoutes)
```

or following change in the only cursor and no changes in all over the code

```
CURSOR cur_security_data IS
    SELECT
    "ID"                  requestId, -- removed "  (double qoutes) from all the alias
    "ROOM"                room,
    "FIRST_NAME"          FIRST_NAME,
    "LAST_NAME"           LAST_NAME
FROM
   "BI_REQUEST_CATERING_ACTIVITY" ;
```

Actually, When you use `"` to wrap your aliases Oracle makes this as case sensitive.
So In your case, "requestId" must be referred to as case sensitive manner.

You are referring to it without `double quotes` in your assignment right side. so actually oracle sees it as `LREC.REQUESTID := L_CUR_SECURITY_DATA(I).REQUESTID;`, But knows no variable named: `REQUESTID`.

This is purely mistake of case sensitive/Insensitive variable name.

for oracle , 
`num1` and `"Num1"` are `NUM1` and `Num1` respectively and both are different.

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks a lot...! it's worked for me. and I have a question regarding this only,
if that select query returns 0 records in cursor I'm getting an error like  referring uninitialized  cursor, how to Handel that exception here

Comment: Ho to handle  cursor exception when the select query returns "zero" records

Comment: That should be the other question and asked as a new question to avoid a mess in a single thread.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57653739/ho-to-handle-cursor-exception-when-the-select-query-returns-zero-records
pls try to answer this