# How to handle cursor exception when the select query returns "zero" records

Tags: oracle, plsql

How to handle cursor exception when the select query returns "zero" records

I have a cursor in a procedure, and after cursor initialization I'm iterating through the cursor to access the data from it.

But the problem is when the cursor select query returns 0 records then it throws exception

> ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection.

How to handle this exception?

---**procedure code**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE BIQ_SECURITY_REPORT 
             (out_chr_err_code   OUT VARCHAR2,
              out_chr_err_msg    OUT VARCHAR2,
              out_security_tab   OUT return_security_arr_result   ,

             )
IS             

      l_chr_srcstage     VARCHAR2 (200);
      lrec               return_security_report;


CURSOR cur_security_data IS
    SELECT
    "ID"                  "requestId",
    "ROOM"                "room",
    "FIRST_NAME"          "FIRST_NAME",
    "LAST_NAME"           "LAST_NAME",

FROM
   "BI_REQUEST_CATERING_ACTIVITY" ;

   TYPE rec_security_data IS TABLE OF cur_security_data%ROWTYPE
   INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
   l_cur_security_data   rec_security_data;  


begin


      OPEN cur_security_data;

      LOOP      
         FETCH cur_security_data
         BULK COLLECT INTO l_cur_security_data
         LIMIT 1000;

         EXIT WHEN l_cur_security_data.COUNT = 0;

        lrec := return_security_report();
        out_security_tab  := return_security_arr_result(return_security_report());
        out_security_tab.delete;


   FOR i IN 1 .. l_cur_security_data.COUNT
       LOOP


        BEGIN  

           l_num_counter                := l_num_counter + 1;
            lrec                         := return_security_report();
       lrec.requestid              := l_cur_security_data(i).requestId ;                                   lrec.room                 := l_cur_security_data(i).room ;                                  lrec.firstName              := l_cur_security_data(i).firstName ;

               IF l_num_counter > 1 
                      THEN
                         out_security_tab.extend();
                         out_security_tab(l_num_counter) := return_security_report();
                 ELSE
              out_security_tab := return_security_arr_result(return_security_report());
                     END IF;
                     out_security_tab(l_num_counter) := lrec; 

        EXCEPTION             
                WHEN OTHERS 
               THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error occurred : '  || SQLERRM);
               END; 

           END LOOP;              
       END LOOP;              


   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('HERE INSIIDE OTHERS' || SQLERRM);
   END;
```

Can you please explain how handle it.

Comment: Add `out_security_tab  := return_security_arr_result();` at begin of your procedure.

Comment: Where is the exception raised? It looks like the issue could be in one of the other procedures that you call. By the way it would be easier to follow if the code was neatly laid out.

Comment: I add like your suggestion I'm getting the following, 
error ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error

Comment: i tried this method and getting the following error,
Other error : ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error

Answer (score 0):

You must be using `out_security_tab`, which is an output parameter in some other code where the procedure is called.

In your procedure, If cursor returns zero rows then the loop will not be executed and your code will not even initialize the `out_security_tab` which will lead to the error that you are facing.

There is a simple way to avoid:

1. initialize `out_security_tab` outside the loop -- which will definitely initialize it
2. You can create one `out variable` containing details as `Y` or `N` based on if cursor rows count -- Not recommended

Cheers!!

Comment: in my case where exactly I have to add that condition, I try to add a condition like this but it doesn't work for me

Comment: `begin
-- Here --
      OPEN cur_security_data;`

Comment: I added in the same position only, In else part, I'm assigning "out_security_tab" with null value.

Comment: No, add it where i have mentioned

Comment: This is not the initialization.. you must have to initialize it to `return_security_arr_result` with all its variable as null. Something like `out_security_tab:=return_security_arr_result(null,null,..)`